# jqueryui tooltip global bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have dynamic elements on the page that come and go, hidden and show etc. Instead of binding tooltip() each time the element is appended to the dom, I would like to set a global handler (via document).
It works except I want a global handler for multiple "items" which doesn't work and I couldn't find a good example for it. This is what I tried:

```
$( document ).tooltip({ // works good if its the only one
    items: ":not(.btn-box-share)",
    ... // close, content, etc (methods)
});

$( document ).tooltip({ //! replaces the previous bind to document..
  items: '.btn-box-share',
  ... // different close, content, etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       $( document ).tooltip({ //
            items: "://
            extraClass:"t3"
        });
```

Using the extra class option and differentiating them with different styling definitions, wether the styling is different or not. the instance should inherit its own properties and work for ya. I havent tried your particular situation, but it should work.

Comment: I don't need this for styling, the class name ".btn-box-share" does not hold eny styling its just for marking. In my example, each "..." has different functions (close, content, etc). I'll update that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed some odd behavior with the items selector. I was able to work around it by building a selector object and then passing the object to the items property. Might be worth a shot here.

You could also bypass items and build the logic into your tooltip functions using hasClass or similar.